# Export execution time xampp

Tags: php, xampp, export, database-backups

I am getting error saying

> your export is incomplete due to low execution time in limit at the php level

In my backup of database. I do the back up of database in task scheduler that is scheduled at 12 midnight. My `max_execution_time` is already big

```
max_execution_time = 5000
```

I already have a big value in PHP.INI I can still change this value to bigger value.

My question is, is there any pros or cons for bigger number in `max_execution_time` in `php.ini`

Comment: local server or online? You are sure you _may_ and _can_ set the max_execution_time? Try to get it after you've set it.

Comment: @Jeff I have it in a local server access through local area network. I am trying to backup the database everyday at 12 midnight but this morning I saw that error and is worried that the database is not up to date?I will have problem because I delete other back up older that 2 weeks

Comment: @Jeff actually i already changed it to 5000 to accommodate the big database can i still increase it to bigger what are the pros and cons?